# Not being able to receive store from mobx provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, mobx, mobx-react

I'm using react-router 3 and here is the code for my routes:

```
export default (
  <Route>
    <Route path="login" component={LoginPage}/>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Dashboard}/>
      <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
      <Route path="form" component={FormPage}/>
      <Route path="table" component={TablePage}/>
      <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage}/>
    </Route>
  </Route>
);
```

Here is my main `Index.js` where I included the `Provider` from `mobx-react`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
require('./favicon.ico');
import './styles.scss';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
import 'flexboxgrid/css/flexboxgrid.css';
import store from './Store.js';

injectTapEventPlugin();

render(
    <Provider store={store}><Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory} /></Provider>, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

`store.js` looks like this:

```
import { autorun, observable } from 'mobx';

class appStore {
    @observable userSession = {
                isUserLogged: false,
                id: 0,
                name: '',
                token: '',
                memberId: 0,
                membershipId: 1000
            }
}

let store = window.store = new appStore;

export default store;

//test
autorun(()=> {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(store.userSession));
})
```

I've already setup mobx for my react app, the `autorun` can log my store.
Then I add the `Provider` around my router and try to log the props in my `App.js`, I'm not receiving my store at all.

I added `@observer` in my `App` component and tried to log my props to check if my store is being passed down but I didn't get it.

Anyone knows why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you have the store available on the window object (`window.store`) so you could access it via that in the child components. However, we should avoid global variables!

`<Provider>` simply acts as a convenience method to make the store available via the context. To allow other components to use, you can use the `@inject` decorator which will work in conjunction with the `<Provider>` to add it to the components props which as been decorated.

As you are using a module system, you could simply `import` the store into each component that requires it and not rely on either the global window scope or the `<Provider>`.

Comment: Well, `redux-react` uses the same way of having a `<Provider>`. Thanks for the advice of avoiding global variables. I'd like to accept your answer as it is another solution of accessing the store. Although, I still want to know why I'm not being able to access the store through the `<Provider>`. Can you help me?

Comment: You'll need to use the `@inject` decorator to make it available in the props of the component that needs it. As you'd be both defining the `@inject` and the provider under it, that won't be possible on the App component.

You can't have both the provider and decorator in the same component. The provider will only work for child components of App. if you import the store into App via a module, then you can use it that way.